# mvc4 :passing locations info to javascript variable for geolocations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc and jquery.
I want to replace the locations by replacing them with multiple cities on a database. I was wondering how I got about doing this.

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [
        ['Hougang', 1.37265, 103.893658],
        ['Punggol', 1.400617, 103.907833],
        ['MacRitchie Reservoir', 1.346002, 103.825436],
        ['Bishan', 1.352051, 103.849125],
        ['Sentosa', 1.251226, 103.830757]
        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 0,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37265, 103.893658),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // Check if user support geo-location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: geolocpoint,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            }
            // Place a marker
            var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: geolocpoint,
                map: map,
                title: 'Your geolocation',
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            });
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

Would it be something on these lines?, the problem is I have no idea how to connect the two.

```
public JsonResult Autolocations()
        {
            var locations = from s in db.Tble_content
                              select s.EN_Title;
            // return namelist.ToList();
            return Json(locations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Many thanks in advance
Hesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ajax to connect the controller with a view, something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("/Locations/Autolocations", null, function (locations) {
          initialize(locations);
    });
});

function initialize(locations) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 0,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37265, 103.893658),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    //the rest of your javascript code
}
```

And your controller should something like this

```
public class LocationsController : Controller    
{
    public JsonResult Autolocations()
    {
        var locations = from s in db.Tble_content
                          select s;
        return Json(locations.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi DZL
Sorry I didn't get back sooner, this is great I tried it but I get an error on the javascript msg box saying [object Object], [object Object] ... would you know why?
but again thanks for this

Comment: I think your problem is using locations[i][1]. I would use locations[i].lat instead of index and your controller action would need to return location objects containing property lat. Can you post the javascript line that is throwing an error?

Comment: Hi Sorry DZL - I did resolve the problem by adding the sql field names 
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]["slatitude"], locations[i]["slongitude"]),... this has done the job. Many thanks for your help
Hesh